# Creating TextView by for loop, only the first created working

Tags: android, for-loop, textview

I am trying to create a brunch of TextView and show them on the screen by a for loop.

But only the first TextView shows the value "123" assigned.

There are still many TextView created but only the first one shows value.

I think I missed something, but do you have idea that what I had missed?

Thanks.

onCreate():

```
 LinearLayout busStopLinearLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        // skipped

        busStopLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bus_stop_linear_layout);

        // skipped

    }
```

The for loop I am asking for:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < closestStop.size(); i++) {
        TextView dummyTxt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        dummyTxt.setLayoutParams(params);

        dummyTxt.setText("123");

        busStopLinearLayout.addView(dummyTxt);

        busStopTextArray.add(dummyTxt);
    }
```

activity.xml

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bus_stop_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This out**

```
LinearLayout busStopLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.busStopLinearLayout); 
for(int i=0; i<closestStop.size(); i++){
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("123");
    text.setTextSize(12);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    busStopLinearLayout.addView(text);
}
```

Comment: I made it work by not using LinearLayout but RelativeLayout

Comment: TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("123");
text.setId(k+1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, k);
busStopLayout.addView(text , params);